# JsonHttpResponse onFailure error when inside adapter

Tags: android, json, http-headers

I have an adapter that has in it many items. When I click on one of them, im reading data from some Json that is connected to the specific item.

I'm using the following code:

```
DiscoverBookAdapter.OnDiscoverBookClickListener listener = new DiscoverBookAdapter.OnDiscoverBookClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DiscoverBooks discoverBooks) {
        bookAdapter.clear();
        Intent intent = new Intent(DiscoverActivity.this, BookDetailActivity.class);
        client = new MyBookClient();
        client.getBooks( discoverBooks.getBookID(), new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response){
                if(response!=null){
                    final MyBook books = MyBook.fromJson(response);
                    bookAdapter.add(books);
                    intent.putExtra( BOOK_DETAIL_KEY, bookAdapter.getItem( 0 ) );
                    intent.putExtra( CASE_KEY,"searching_book" );
                    intent.putExtra( ORIGIN_KEY, "profile" );
                    startActivity( intent );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                Log.d("Failed: ", ""+statusCode);
                Log.d("Error : ", "" + throwable);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

For some reason, like the first 5 clicks gives me the following error:

```
V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 310 from 1 (31000%)
W/JsonHttpRH: onFailure(int, Header[], Throwable, JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback was received
    cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:446)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:160)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

After this 5 or so clicks it does the job like needed.

Is there any reason that it is not working for the first time? or why it gives this error anyway if the code does its job.

Thank you

Comment: I recommend you to make the request in the detail activity and avoid to send all detail info in the transaction. About the error response you could check all the request/response information using a proxy application in your computer. I use Charles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android-async-http's official github page. It seems similar issue:
https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http/issues/1200

Comment: I added all the 3 and it seems to work, I hope its not temporary =P Thank you!